# How to set storedprocedure selected datas in a dataset and retrive it in a c# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to select some bulk data from database through stored procedure. I have written procedure and I am not aware about how to set these result in a data set and how to retrieve this data set in c# code. My procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Leavetypedetails Report](
@code nvarchar(50)
 )
AS
declare @dataset as nvarchar(50)
BEGIN
select EmpCode,LeaveType,FromDate,Todate,Noofleave,Balance,Transfer,cash from LeaveTypeDetails where EmpCode=@code
END
```

I want to set this result in a data set and want to retrieve in my c# code. My code is

```
 public string leavestatus(string code, DateTime date1, DateTime date2, int month, int year, int dept, string value)
{
  string data = "";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Leavetypedetails Report");
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = code;
  conn.nonquery(cmd);
  return data;
 }

 protected void view_Click(object sender, Event Args e)
  {
   ??I want to show the rerun data in a grid-view(GridView1)

  }
```

I know its a lengthy question, even though expect yours help...Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not that `Trivial` in fact `SO` as well as the internet has tons of working examples of this.. here is a link [C# Code Samples](http://www.google.com) click on it and type `C# Binding DataGridView to DataAdapter, DataTable, or DataSet `p.s. this is not a coding servuce`

Comment: Find the result by executing procedure and fill it into a data set. then bind the  dataset as gridview datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public void bindgrid()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(connStr, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "your sp";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        Session["datasource"] = ds; // In case u want to store ur dataset in session and use it anywhere further
        Gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public DataTable leavestatus(string code, DateTime date1, DateTime date2, 
                         int month, int year, int dept, string value)
{
  string data = "";
  DataSet dstData = new DataSet("Data");
  SQLDataAdapter adpData;
  adpData = new SQLDataAdapter("Leavetypedetails Report", conn);
  adpData.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).value = code;
  adpData.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  adpData.Fill(dstData); 
  return dstData.tables[0];
 }

 protected void view_Click(object sender, Event Args e)
  {
        Grid.Datasource = leavestatus(.....);
        Grid.DataBind();
  }
```

Comment: `Grid.Datasource = leavestatus(.....);` this is wrong you should return the dstData like you are doing however you need to bind the Grid.Datasource to a `adpData.Tables[0]` for example

Comment: Yea thnx for that..  @MethodMan